# Tableau Rest Api with Personal Access Token stopped working

Tags: tableau-api

We have an automation calling Tableau rest api. It uses personal access token authentication, and it worked for quite some time.

Yesterday queries started failing.
When using client library `tableauserverclient`,

```py
import tableauserverclient as TSC
from tableauserverclient.models import JobItem

tableau_token_name = "xxxx"
tableau_token = "xxxx"
tableau_server_url = "xxxx"
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(tableau_token_name, tableau_token, 'xxxx')
server = TSC.Server(tableau_server_url, use_server_version=True)
workbook  = server.workbooks.get_by_id("xxxx")
```

it returns an error

```bash
Job 603db386-4d1c-4705-9d2c-5da054bc810d failed with notes ['com.tableausoftware.server.status.reporting.TableauRuntimeException: [Simba][ThriftExtension] (8) 
Authentication/authorization error occurred. 
Error details: Bad status with no error message: 
Unauthorized/Forbidden: Status code : 403\nInvalid username or password.']
```

I tried calling it with curl

```bash
curl --location --globoff '{{server}}/api/3.6/auth/signin' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data '{
  "credentials": {
     "site": {
        "contentUrl": "{{content-url}}"
     },
     "personalAccessTokenName": "{{pat-name}}",
     "personalAccessTokenSecret": "{{pat-secret}}"
  }
}'
```

which returns

```json
{"error":{"summary":"Signin Error","detail":"The personal access token you provided is invalid.","code":"401001"}}
```

I tried generating new tokens multiple times with the same result.

Where could I look further to debug the issue?

Comment: One reason it stopped working could be the 6-month expiration date on the token. This doesn't explain why you are not able to generate a new token though.

Have you tried a new token name and token? I'm wondering when a token expires whether the name could possibly get stuck as expired even if regenerating the token.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Server API error messages can be frustratingly opaque. But there's a few things I'd check:

- How long after generating the new tokens are you waiting to use them? Anecdotally, I've found a variable lag before they are 'active', anywhere from 1-15 minutes.
- The comment from @vizyourdata is possibly the original cause, though with regular use I think they take 1 year to expire by default
- Do you have any concurrent calls using the token as well? If you use the same token in two places at the same time, one call will be invalidated
- How are you getting the token_name and token in your script? If via environment variables: check that it's pulling them correctly without error (e.g. print the variables before passing them to TSC)

I also notice you aren't actually authenticating in your example code (at least as far as I've always used it), though it doesn't explain it only just recently failing, or the CURL failing. Have included the corrected code below just in case.

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
from tableauserverclient.models import JobItem

tableau_token_name = "xxxx"
tableau_token = "xxxx"
tableau_server_url = "xxxx"
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(tableau_token_name, tableau_token, 'xxxx')
server = TSC.Server(tableau_server_url, use_server_version=True)

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth): # Modified here
    workbook  = server.workbooks.get_by_id("xxxx")
```